# Stuck in a teleporting loop

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I tried to use a command block to teleport me, but I used a repeating one by mistake, and I'm like three walls away from it facing away so I can't delete it. So I'm stuck and I can't even turn my head and its on my favorite world. What do I do? Minecraft PE on an iPad.

Comment: Try finding out the coordinates of the command block and setting it to air.